# extracting unchanged raw phone numbers with phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher

Tags: python, regex, phone-number, data-extraction

I am trying to extact phone numbers, from a text. But I don't want phones to be reformatted, number parts extracted or anything else, but I want to get only unchanged, not reformatted, raw original strings of phone numbers, extracted from the text.
I tried "phonenumbers" library (https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers), with PhoneNumberMatcher() method. It works great, in sense of getting formatted phone number, which is what I don't need, I need only original substrings of phone numbers. Is there a way to do it?

```
for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(text, "US"):
    unformatted_phone = match.number
    #formatted_phone = str(match.number)
    #formatted_phone = phonenumbers.format_number(match.number, None)
    formatted_phone = phonenumbers.format_number(match.number, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, it is .raw_string

```
phones = []
for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(text, "US"):
    phone = match.raw_string
    phones.append(phone)
```